# How to disable some options in Word styles context menu

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I cannot find the idMso for the styles context menu in wordcontrols.xlsx. I would like to disable some of the options in the context menu.

Do anyone know the names of the controls?

[image]

Some ribbon controls are disabled like this:

```
<command idMso="DeleteStyle" enabled="false"/>
<command idMso="StylesRedefineStyle" enabled="false"/>
<command idMso="StylesDialogClassic" enabled="false"/>
```

The context menu buttons are disabled here:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuTextEdit">
  <button idMso="ParagraphDialog" enabled="false" />
  <button idMso="FontDialog" enabled="false" />
</contextMenu>
```

And I do not know the idMso for word styles context menu.

Comment: Show the/some code to get answers.

Comment: @UweKeim added code

Answer (score 0):

The first two look like:

- StylesModifyStyle
- StylesRenameStyle

Take care when disabling these controls as they are not specific to that context menu.

Neither the context menu nor the other two controls seem to be listed.

Comment: I already tried these control names but they don't do anything.